# A smallest grammar algorithm can recurse by decomposing into terminals, then repeating with increased alphabet.

Tags: optimization, proof-writing, formal-languages, recursive-algorithms, formal-grammar

Please scan the article on the [smallest grammar problem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest_grammar_problem) It is a simply-stated, major open problem because it directly relates to $\text{P vs NP}$ if an answer in either direction can be given.

Let $t \leqslant s$ mean that $t$ occurs somewhere in $s$ as a substring, or alternatively $utv = s$.  Imagine you have a smallest grammar to look at.  Call it $G$.  It can be fully expanded to its input (for smallest grammar algorithm) $s \in \Sigma_s$.  But what if you didn't expand any rules that are *irreducible:* any $T \to t$ such that for all $u \leqslant t$:
 $$|u| \lt 2$$ or 
$$\#_tu \lt 2,$$ where $\#_t u$ is the maximal number of non-overlapping occurences of the substring $u \leqslant t$.  This number can be computed by leftmost packing $u$ into $t$.

What we should be left with is a starting rule $S' \to c_0T_{i_1} c_1 \cdots T_{i_n} c_n$ together with the rules $T_i, i=1\dots r$. Call this grammar $G'$.

**Then, is it true that $S' \Rightarrow S$, or in other words that $G$ is a smallest grammar of start rule of $G'$ together with including $T_i$ rules from $G'$?**

If true, then one possible recursive smallest grammar algorithm, while it still may be difficult to compute, is to first decompose fully into *irreducibles* and then run the algorithm again on the new alphabet $\Sigma_s \cup \{T_1, \dots, T_r\}$.

Therefore please help me prove or disprove the idea.

Comment: I would be happy to help you, but your question is difficult to understand. Here are some questions: what is $\Sigma_s$? "Imagine you have a smallest grammar to look at": what kind of grammar?  Regular? Context-free? Context sensitive? a smallest grammar to do what? smallest in which sense? I suggest you to give an example.

Comment: And I don't see the point of giving an answer (still hard to understand) to your own questions just half an hour after you asked it.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin $\Sigma_s = $ the smallest alphabet you can have such that $s$ is a string over $\Sigma_s$.  Read up on the smallest grammar problem to understand more.  I cannot re-introduce it in every post I make (I make a lot of these posts).  It is a simple statement that seems difficult to prove either way.  Anyhow, it's concerning single-string, context-free grammars, and whether or not there is a deterministic polynomial time algorithm for computing any of the possible smallest grammars for a given, arbitrary string $s$.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin The point is that the proof is not as hard as it first seemed.  But you could also give a different proof, or indicate a problem in my proof, in your answer.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Also, writing MSE posts helps me think through problems.  Would you rather me delete this nice content?  After all, no one else is making smallest grammar content.  This idea seems interesting at least to me, and I would like to refer to it later, even if all my local data got lost.

Comment: If you need a notion that was already introduced, please give a link to your previous question. I agree that you cannot re-introduce everything, but the reader is not supposed to browse  through all your questions to find the appropriate definition.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin  The reader is expected to know about the smallest grammar problem just as a person studying tensor analysis (a way more complicated subject) is expected to know basic definitions. It is a wikipedia article away.

Comment: Then give the wikipedia link !!!

Comment: @J.-E.Pin  Sounds like a plan.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\text{I}$ be the complete list of irreducible rules in $G$, and $S'= c_0 I_1 c_1 \cdots I_n c_n$, $ \ I_i \in \text{I}$  be expansion of $G$ up to not expanding any $I \in \text{I}$. Since $G'$ is a grammar for $s$ any grammar derived from $G'$ by taking a smallest grammar of $S'$ is also a grammar for $s$.  This means that if $G$ is not in the set of smallest grammars derivable from $G'$ in this manner, then the smallest grammar size derivable $G'$ is strictly greater than $|G|$ (the cost of $G$: sum of lengths of RHS of rules).

But $G$ is in particular derivable from $G'$ by creating new rules and applying them to to grammar substrings (collapsing them into a variable symbol).  This is true since we built $G'$ by doing the inverse operation of deleting rules and rule variables into strings.

Therfore, despite this inelegant proof, $G$ is a smallest grammar of $S'$ together with the terminal rules $I_i \in G'$.

Not sure, but we may need to indicate that this smallest grammar algorithm works by creating rules and collapsing into variables.